# Can’t use icons for shortcuts from network in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts, icons

I am using icons in server PC in network for shortcuts in users' desktops. On all my Vista/Win7 machines they are fine and the icons are what I set them to be. On all my Win8 machines the icon is just a blank white square. If I right-click and view the icon, the correct image appears. But when the user is looking at the desktop the image is blank. What is reason for this? What is solution?

Comment: in server PC in network for shortcuts in users' desktops.... Could you kindly clarify this location?

Comment: We have a Windows server 2003 PC and we are trying to use icon files in that PC for shortcuts in other PC's connected in network.Same thing working with other OS.But on all my Win8 machines the icon is just a blank white square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is a solution,I just find out

Enable this policy:run gpedit.msc->Computer configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/File Explorer/Allow the use of remote paths in file shortcut icons.
This is a new Setting in Windows 8/2012 and seems to have some security related Background although I found no real description.